# Unable to Select Existing Android SDK during Android Studio Installation

Tags: android, android-studio

I am unable to select existing Android SDK as the File chooser is blank.

Also the license acceptance screen is blank. 
I already have eclipse installed on my system for Android development.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPCKX.png)

My System configuration is as follows :
Windows 7 - 64bit
i3 processor
4GB RAM
JDK 1.8.0_51

Help me figure out the problem

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by manually entering the complete path to the existing Android SDK. Still don't know why the file chooser and the license agreement screen was blank.

Answer (score 0):

Even though there was an error and sdk path wasn't found, just click `finish` button and you will see the android studio welcome page.There,click on `configure`>`projects defaults`> `projects structure` and point out the path corresponding to `sdk` and `jdk` manually! and you're done .